# How do I get the race ID of a custom race?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a mod that adds playable children in Skyrim. However, the playable child races are different from the races that NPC children use; they have different IDs, models and textures and so on.

When I type `help race 0` or `help "race" 4`, the custom races don't come up, so I don't know the IDs of them. I want to change some of the children to the custom child race so that they look better, but I don't know how to get the IDs of those custom races.

Is there any console command that can be used to identify a race ID other than just using the `GetIsRace` command (which only tells you if an actor is or isn't a specific race)?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I figured it out. The Race IDs weren't showing up only because the console couldn't scroll up enough. 
I ended up opening the mod up in TESEdit and found the Race IDs there so I could use them in-game.

Answer (score 0):

First of all look at the mod page (from wherever you downloaded it), if it doesnt tell the Race ID you can always use the command showracemenu to change your race. In showracemenu all the custom races and cosmetics should appear normally.

Keep in mind that showracemenu can swap your skill levels and magicka/health/stamina. Using TGM before entering showracemenu should make it less buggy. But you can then change it with "player.setav  <#>" if something isnt as it should.

Comment: I'm not looking to change my character, I'm looking to change an NPC, so showracemenu wouldn't work for that. The site I downloaded it from doesn't list the Race IDs.